# Laravel storage::download(path_to_file) not working as required with .doc/.docx

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-storage

I am trying to Storage::download(file_path) but with pdf file type it showing pdf file in postman, however with .doc/.docx it is returning some garbage value. I want to return doc file like pdf, below is attached pdf and doc postman response:

[image: when downloading pdf file]

[image: when downloading doc file]

Comment: This feels like a "Postman just doesn't include a MS Word renderer" issue and not something you can do anything about.

Comment: I am also using react-doc-viewer and with pdf file it shows correctly but with doc it don't, also in api request which is getting this file there pdf is shown correctly but not doc.

Comment: Postman does not include an MS word renderer however `react-doc-viewer` is meant to work so share what code you tried for that since it does not seem a backend issue. The result you are seeing in postman seems to be a correct docx file if you just see it as binary

Comment: const docs =[{uri:Api.document(data.id).document.getUrl()}]
 <DocViewer
                           config={{
                            header: {
                              disableHeader: false,
                              disableFileName: false,
                              retainURLParams: false,
                            },
                          }}
                         documents={docs} 
                         pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
                        />